# Hide the top bar in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How do I hide the top bar in UITabBarController using OBJ-C code (without using Interface Builder) ?

Please see the image in the link below to better understand my requirement.

http://skitch.com/jugsvn/dxkr7/iphone-simulator

I already have another toolbar as you can see and I don't want this. I'm not using XIB / NIB files and creating all the objects using plain OBJ-C code.

Cheers
Jugs

Comment: Vijayakumar. I think that is navigation bar is there in your image. so try this one,  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The topBar is part of the UINavigationController not the UITabBarController, you can hide it by putting the following in your viewWillAppear method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

But I'm pretty sure the navigationBar is always on top, so I think the bar you want to hide is actually your own toolbar.

```
self.myToolBar.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

Comment: this is actually the right answer just not the right language i.e obj-c