# Tabs under UITabBarController's More button have 2 navigation bars

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have 6 view controllers on a UITabBarController. Each of them has a UINavigationBar at the top of them (Not linked to a UINavigationController), for showing the title of that view controller, and some buttons for controlling it. This was fine while I had 5 controllers, as no 'More' button would appear, but when I add a 6th, the more button appears. The tabs under that end up having two UINavigationBars! One is the one I added, with my title, the other is created by the TabBar and has a 'Back' arrow to go back to the more page. How can I fix this, either by merging them or otherwise?

Thanks, if you want screenshots just ask.

Here's a screenshot

[image: http://imgur.com/S9rFR]

The brown one is a UINavigationBar subclass I made, and added to the view in IB. The other one was added by the Tab Bar controller.

Comment: yes please. And also mention how you are adding navigationBar on thoes viewController.

Comment: OK. Shall upload screenshots in a sec. The navigationBars are added in interface builder, in the xib.

Comment: @Ravin I've added some screenshots to the main post now. What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated answer please re-read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need to merge them.As you need more tabs so More controller will apear and once you navigate in, it will put back button(more). In order to solve this and maintain your brown `navigationBar` you will need to use `navigationController` for those `tabs` in more(only for extras, not for all). This will put more(the back button) on your `navigationBar`.

But Remember In `more` you will have `edit` option also using which user can change position of tabs. So in that case this problem may reappear for other controllers. So please check if you can disable the editing of `tabs`(rearrangement). If not then you should think the same for other `controllers` also(in other `tabs`)

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll have a look for another solution (because rewriting all my controllers to use navigationControllers might be difficult) but might come back to this.

Comment: hey, its just five minutes task. what you have to do is add navigationController on the tabBarController rather than usual tabBarItems. It will make all of your viewController of type NavigationController and then you just need to change the navBar appearance. thanks

Comment: Followed your tips, but I cannot hide it, or avoid the push when i came from the "more" screen. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Followed all of your tips but no luck, until: I tested this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397506/468868

Basically, you are right @Ravin, we must wrap the items in NavigationControllers, but after that, you must specify that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Now, I just need to figure it out how to remove the navigationController from the "More" view