# Is is possible to create a tabbarcontroller that does not have elements hidden within "More" section?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm currently running into issues similar to the ones described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684646/tabs-under-uitabbarcontrollers-more-button-have-2-navigation-bars) post and am wondering if it is possible in a tabbarcontroller to not show the "More" icon and display all of the view controllers in the tab bar?

The issue of reconciling the show and hide becomes problematic if I assume that some views have navigation bars and that a user may change the order of the tabs, so hiding and showing tab bars becomes another facet of the project I will need to keep track of in appearance and disappearance methods.

Per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/moreNavigationController), the morenavigationcontroller is something that does not is set in the tabbar's vc array, but is merely a property